# How can I access foreign table in my nodejs TypeORM code

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, typeorm

[This is my database view and I need to access this foreign table using Typeform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGdJM.png) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GBJV.png)

I can only access my table using their entities but there is no entity in case of a foreign table so how can I access them in my code

```
const employeRepo = AppDatasource.getRepository(Employee);
const employeedata = await employeRepo.find()
```

This is how I access my other tables